# Xamarin Android async await not await method

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin.android

I m doing a Xamarin Android project, I wan't to display a list of objects from my SQLite database into a RecyclerView.

The RecyclerView is in a Fragment. I wan't to display the list when I open this fragment, and when I go back from an Activity to this fragment I wan't to refresh the data of the recycler view.

For know I get the correct values, but I don't know why the `GetMyObjectsAsync` result is not awaited Why ?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.Widget;
using Android.Views;
using Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation;
using System.Linq;
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Util;
using System;

namespace POCProject.Droid.Fragments
{
    public class MyCustomFragment : Fragment
    {

        private IMyObjectsService _myObjectsService;

        List<ObjModel> myObjects { get; set; } = new List<ObjModel>();

        RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

        MyObjectsRecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter;



        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            _myObjectsService = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IMyObjectsService>();

        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_my_objects_list, container, false) as View;

            mRecyclerView = view.FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.MyRecyclerView);


            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mRecyclerView.Context);


            mRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

            return view;
        }

        public override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();
            Task.Run(async () => { 
                try
                {
                    myObjects = await GetMyObjectsAsync(); // Here it's not awaited the result why ?
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }

            });
            mAdapter = new MyObjectsRecyclerViewAdapter(myObjects);
            Console.WriteLine("--------------------OnResume Called-------------------- " + myObjects.Count()); // Always 0 why ?

            mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(mAdapter);
        }



        private async Task<List<ObjModel>> GetMyObjectsAsync(){
            Console.WriteLine("--------------------GetMyObjectsAsync Called--------------------");
            var result = await _myObjectsService.GetAllAsync(); // Get objects in sqlite databases
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------- result" + result.Value.Count() + "--------------------");  // Return the correct value for example 5

            List<ObjModel> myOjectsTmp = new List<ObjModel>();


            if (!result.HasErrors && result.HasValue)
            {
                foreach (var obj in result.Value)
                {
                    myOjectsTmp.Add(obj);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("-------------------- myOjectsTmp"+ myOjectsTmp.Count() + "--------------------"); // Return the correct value for example 5
            }

            return myOjectsTmp;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know that it is not awaiting?

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi Because myObjects in the try catch always return 0 instead of the result of the GetMyObjectsAsync() method which return 5, nothing is display. I see it with the console WriteLine too

Comment: Just call `GetMyObjectsAsync()` without any return type. and set adapter after the loop inside `GetMyObjectsAsync()`

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi It's just working one time, When I go back to the fragment from another activity it pass from OnResume but nothing is refreshing

Comment: are you aware of [AsyncListUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/AsyncListUtil.html) or [paging library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html) ? you dont really have to do that async stuff as it can be done for you by those helper classes

Comment: @pskink I will look at it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Move these two line:

```
mAdapter = new MyObjectsRecyclerViewAdapter(myObjects);
mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(mAdapter);
```

after

```
 myObjects = await GetMyObjectsAsync();
```

Like:

```
   myObjects = await GetMyObjectsAsync();
Activity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
                    {
    mAdapter = new MyObjectsRecyclerViewAdapter(myObjects);
    mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(mAdapter);
 });
```

Comment: Same behavior than the other solution but I have this message in the application output : "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."

Comment: It seems working, I need to do some more tests and I will tell you give me minutes

Comment: Without Activity it's not recognizing the method